# Can I setup a local webserver using ArchLinux and VirtualBox

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, webserver

I intend to create a local webserver using ArchLinux and VirtualBox for testing purposes.
I just wonder if Arch Linux has what it takes to create a fully functional webserver?

Comment: Question is vague, was the server provided by VBox, or locally in the Arch ?

Comment: The answer is too short, so I post it as a comment: “Yes.” (If you wanto a more detailled answer we need a more detailled question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at "Comprehensive Server Guide" - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Comprehensive_Server_Guide